# Moving from Tika LanguageIdentifier to Tika LanguageDetector

Tags: scala, apache-tika

Our current Scala code runs with Tika 1.13+ and we use the now deprecated `LanguageIdentifier` code like so:

```
import org.apache.tika.language.LanguageIdentifier

object DetectLanguage {
  def apply(input: String): String = {
    if (input.isEmpty) ""
    else new LanguageIdentifier(input).getLanguage
}
```

As `LanguageIdentifier` is now deprecated, we're trying to implement the `LanguageDetector` class instead: https://tika.apache.org/1.15/api/org/apache/tika/language/detect/LanguageDetector.html.

However, we cannot seem to get it to work. As we are hoping to get the ISO code, I tried swapping out for this `CharsetMatch` command (https://tika.apache.org/1.16/api/org/apache/tika/parser/txt/CharsetMatch.html#getLanguage--). But swapping out `LanguageIdentifier` for `CharsetMatch` leads to compile errors, as does trying to use the `Detect` calls here: https://tika.apache.org/1.15/api/org/apache/tika/language/detect/LanguageDetector.html.

The usage examples still seem to point to the deprecated library, which is the usual way I learn. Thanks very much for your help.

Comment: The Apache Tika App uses [LanguageHandler.getLanguage().getLanguage()](https://tika.apache.org/1.17/api/org/apache/tika/language/detect/LanguageHandler.html#getLanguage--) - would that work for you too?

Comment: Thanks! It would be great to ry, but I can't seem to get it to compile. :/

Comment: Make sure you're using Apache Tika 1.17, then look at the source code for the Tika CLI to see the use!

Answer (score 1):

you can use LanguageDetector as it is used

```
    public static String detectLanguage(String text) {
    LanguageDetector detector = new OptimaizeLangDetector().loadModels();
    detector.addText(text);
    return detector.detect().getLanguage();
}
```